# iframe with src starting with `http` automatically opens in safari rather than in Webapp

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, iphone-web-app

I've a WebApp(for ios) which have a lot of pages in it. Almost in all pages I've iframes with sources that start with `http`. When I click on this link of one of those pages, safari browser open up before I can see that web page. The problem I figured out is that every link starting with `http` will automatically open in new window of safari and without http it stays inside my webapp. How can I solve this problem? can I remove `http://` from each page before the page load? or is there anyother solution for it?

`<iframe src="http://www.google.com"/>` Opens in safari, out of the webapp whereas `<iframe src="www.google.com"/>` opens in the same webapp page.

Comment: Just asking, what is the WebApp being made with?

Comment: What do you mean by "webapp"? Application using WebView?

Comment: Making WebApp for my iphone, with html, javascript and jquery.

Comment: `http://www.google.com` response `HTTP 302` if using `<iframe>` and no open safari (testing in iOS 7)

Comment: Not working for me. Not a single link with `http://` is opening in the same window of webapp, directly in safari after closing the app.

Comment: I think I should find some program that will open up my file and remove any `http://` text. Because I've a lot pages but I've list of all those pages.